# Does "кэса" decline in Russian?

Tags: грамматика

Which one is correct?:

> Все монахи были одеты в **кэсу**.

or

> Все монахи были одеты в **кэса**.

And which syllable must be stressed?

Comment: Why not "одеты в кэсы"?

Comment: @user4419802 - Would that be correct? Does it have plural form?

Comment: It's always hard to say with those foreign words. It seems that usually "кэса" is translated into "ряса". So I'd choose "Все монахи были одеты в (буддийские) рясы".

Comment: Where is the stress in this word?

Comment: @thorn - I myself don't know.

Comment: Theoretically, it's the stress that determines the answer to your question. If the word-final "а" is stressed, the word is indeclinable.

Comment: @thorn wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на последний вопрос: слово "кэса" было заимствовано, скорее всего, из японского языка (хирагана: けさ, ромадзи: kesa, иероглифическую запись сервер почему-то не пропускает.) **В русском языке слова, заимствованные из японского, как правило, произносятся с ударением на предпоследний слог** (http://miuki.info/2010/09/udarenie-v-yaponskom-yazyke/).  По ссылке приведён список исключений. Единственное неочевидное в списке - слова с долгим слогом в японском языке, всё остальное к слову "кэса" явно не имеет отношения. Но в хирагане долгие слоги записываются двумя символами (http://lingust.ru/japanese/japanese-lessons/lesson4), а в слове кэсу, написанном хираганой, символов столько же, сколько и слогов (http://www.behindthename.com/name/kesa/submitted).  Поэтому слово "кэса" скорее всего произносится с ударением на первый слог, хотя можно ещё спросить знающих японский язык и/или русскоязычных дзен-буддистов.

По вопросам склонения вам на форум японистов. По крайней мере в отношении имён и топонимов у них нет единого мнения, хотя в академической литературе японские имена и топонимы обычно не склоняются. (http://info-japan.ru/forum/yaponskiy-yazyk/nuzhno-li-sklonyat-yaponskie-imena-i-toponimy)